# Trouble querying expenses on a PO in SuiteQL (NetSuite)

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

I'm trying to query the expense lines listed on a Purchase Order in SuiteQL. Looking at the Schema/Analytics Browser and other documentation hasn't given me any success.

[For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXfme.png)

I can query the items by joining transactionline.transaction to transaction.id but I'm unable to find how to query the expenses.

Answer (score 0):

Expense lines are stored in the `transactionLine` table.  You should be able to access them in your query with the join you have described.  Check for any conditions that might be excluding them, and if you still don't see them, post your query so we can reproduce and check it.

BTW: A better source of documentation for SuiteQL is the Records Catalog at https://{{accountid}}.app.netsuite.com/app/recordscatalog/rcbrowser.nl?whence=